# Help in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, web-config

Well, I am modifying an application in ASP.NET. This application was originally connected to an Oracle8i database, my idea is to connect to a new exactly the same but in SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I change the class that handles the connection and remove the errors that Visual Studio tells me I run http://localhost/ page jumps me an error like this.

> Error instance. Description: An
>   unhandled exception when you run the
>   current web request. Check the stack
>   trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Error de instancia.  Descripción:
>   Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la
>   solicitud Web actual. Revise el
>   seguimiento de la pila para obtener
>   más información acerca del error y
>   dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción:
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Error de instancia.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> ```
> Línea 1535:            using (SqlCommand.Connection)
> Línea 1536:            {
> Línea 1537:                SqlCommand.Connection.Open();
> Línea 1538:                Table.Load(SqlCommand.ExecuteReader());
> Línea 1539:            }
> ```

And I have another question. In the web.config file is a line like this.

```
<add key="DatabaseProvider" value="Test.App.Oracle8i"/>
```

I thought. Oracle8i was referring to the class that I edited and then as I changed the name to SqlServer then left it as follows

```
<add key="DatabaseProvider" value="Test.App.SqlServer"/>
```

And if you do not mind but my connection string I'm using in the web.config is like this.

```
<add name="cString" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=TESTDATABASE;User Id=testuser;Password=testpassword;"/>
```

It might not have looked good, but I need to guide me I've read many times the code and although I understand that is supposed to do almost everything I can not get that error.

Comment: Why are you not using the existing `ConnectionStrings` config section?

Comment: why is that you put double \\ in the connectionstring value

Comment: Well I'm new to this so I looked at some tutorials online and I saw that so defined the connection with sql server.

Comment: I have this ConnectionStrings<connectionStrings>
  <add name="cString" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=TESTDATABASE;User Id=testuser;Password=testpassword;"/>
 </connectionStrings>

Comment: Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing the extra '\' in the connection string.

It should be:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="cString" 
       connectionString="Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=TESTDATABASE;User Id=testuser;Password=testpassword;"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Well I have used that connection string before, but when I do it says can not connect.